# Function points() does not show in the plot

Tags: r, plot

I tried using points() to add values to my plot, but only the original plot works and the function doesn't do anything or raise any errors. I have the functions walk.effectiveleg.length and walk.effectivehip.height defined previously and they can be plotted just fine on their own, but I can't figure out how to plot them together. Does anyone know what could be going on?

I have used points in other plots in the same notebook and it runs just fine, just not on this one.

```
plot(walk.hip[,1], walk.effectivehip.height, col="blue")

points(walk.hip[,1], walk.effectiveleg.length, col="red")
```

Comment: Note that `points()` will not change the `x` and `y` limits for the plot. Do your new points fall in the same region? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: that was it, totally makes sense! apologies for the badly detailed question, and thanks for your help!